# Upgrading to quarkus 3.5 raise errors at execution (about @Claim without ClaimValue wrapper)

Tags: java, quarkus

I am upgrading my quarkus application from 3.4.3 to 3.5.3. According to this [Migration Guide](https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/wiki/Migration-Guide-3.5), there is no mention of a breaking change about claim definition and @Claim annotation.

However, I have this error message when I do a `mvn quarkus:dev`:

```
ERROR [io.qua.dep.dev.IsolatedDevModeMain] (main) Failed to start quarkus: java.lang.RuntimeException: io.quarkus.builder.BuildException: Build failure: Build failed due to errors
        [error]: Build step io.quarkus.smallrye.jwt.deployment.SmallRyeJwtProcessor#registerOptionalClaimProducer threw an exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: java.lang.String type can not be used to represent JWT claims in @Singleton or @ApplicationScoped beans, make the bean @RequestScoped or wrap this type with org.eclipse.microprofile.jwt.ClaimValue or jakarta.inject.Provider or jakarta.enterprise.inject.Instance
        at io.quarkus.smallrye.jwt.deployment.SmallRyeJwtProcessor.registerOptionalClaimProducer(SmallRyeJwtProcessor.java:188)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
        at io.quarkus.deployment.ExtensionLoader$3.execute(ExtensionLoader.java:849)
        at io.quarkus.builder.BuildContext.run(BuildContext.java:282)
        at org.jboss.threads.ContextHandler$1.runWith(ContextHandler.java:18)
        at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$Task.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:2513)
        at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1538)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
        at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:501)
        at io.quarkus.runner.bootstrap.AugmentActionImpl.runAugment(AugmentActionImpl.java:336)
        at io.quarkus.runner.bootstrap.AugmentActionImpl.createInitialRuntimeApplication(AugmentActionImpl.java:253)
        at io.quarkus.runner.bootstrap.AugmentActionImpl.createInitialRuntimeApplication(AugmentActionImpl.java:60)
        at io.quarkus.deployment.dev.IsolatedDevModeMain.firstStart(IsolatedDevModeMain.java:113)
        at io.quarkus.deployment.dev.IsolatedDevModeMain.accept(IsolatedDevModeMain.java:438)
        at io.quarkus.deployment.dev.IsolatedDevModeMain.accept(IsolatedDevModeMain.java:56)
        at io.quarkus.bootstrap.app.CuratedApplication.runInCl(CuratedApplication.java:138)
        at io.quarkus.bootstrap.app.CuratedApplication.runInAugmentClassLoader(CuratedApplication.java:93)
        at io.quarkus.deployment.dev.DevModeMain.start(DevModeMain.java:131)
        at io.quarkus.deployment.dev.DevModeMain.main(DevModeMain.java:62)
Caused by: io.quarkus.builder.BuildException: Build failure: Build failed due to errors
        [error]: Build step io.quarkus.smallrye.jwt.deployment.SmallRyeJwtProcessor#registerOptionalClaimProducer threw an exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: java.lang.String type can not be used to represent JWT claims in @Singleton or @ApplicationScoped beans, make the bean @RequestScoped or wrap this type with org.eclipse.microprofile.jwt.ClaimValue or jakarta.inject.Provider or jakarta.enterprise.inject.Instance
        at io.quarkus.smallrye.jwt.deployment.SmallRyeJwtProcessor.registerOptionalClaimProducer(SmallRyeJwtProcessor.java:188)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
        at io.quarkus.deployment.ExtensionLoader$3.execute(ExtensionLoader.java:849)
        at io.quarkus.builder.BuildContext.run(BuildContext.java:282)
        at org.jboss.threads.ContextHandler$1.runWith(ContextHandler.java:18)
        at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$Task.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:2513)
        at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1538)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
        at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:501)

        at io.quarkus.builder.Execution.run(Execution.java:123)
        at io.quarkus.builder.BuildExecutionBuilder.execute(BuildExecutionBuilder.java:79)
        at io.quarkus.deployment.QuarkusAugmentor.run(QuarkusAugmentor.java:160)
        at io.quarkus.runner.bootstrap.AugmentActionImpl.runAugment(AugmentActionImpl.java:332)
        ... 9 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: java.lang.String type can not be used to represent JWT claims in @Singleton or @ApplicationScoped beans, make the bean @RequestScoped or wrap this type with org.eclipse.microprofile.jwt.ClaimValue or jakarta.inject.Provider or jakarta.enterprise.inject.Instance
        at io.quarkus.smallrye.jwt.deployment.SmallRyeJwtProcessor.registerOptionalClaimProducer(SmallRyeJwtProcessor.java:188)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
        at io.quarkus.deployment.ExtensionLoader$3.execute(ExtensionLoader.java:849)
        at io.quarkus.builder.BuildContext.run(BuildContext.java:282)
        at org.jboss.threads.ContextHandler$1.runWith(ContextHandler.java:18)
        at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$Task.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:2513)
        at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1538)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
        at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:501)
```

If I wrap all my `@Claim` types in my code with `ClaimValue<>` the error disappears and i am able to run my application normally.

Is it a bug or may I miss something about the migration ?

Comment: here the reason https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/pull/36183